# Как сконфигурировать IIS и ASP .NET Core WebApi для слушания внешних запросов и запросов из localhost?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-core, iis

При разработке в VS конфигурирую параметры запуска в файле Properties/launchSettings.json для запуска в IIS Express(который дергает VS).
Если использовать боевой IIS необходимо указать привязку(тип, IP, Порт, Имя узла) при добавлении сайта.

Останется ли необходимость испльзовать launchSettings.json?

Где какие настройки указать?

И вообще возможна ли такая маршрутизация?

Допустим мне нужно что бы запросы приходили:

1. извне по https://mysite.com:443
2. локальные по http://localhost:7000

Comment: Возможно. Для этого в *IIS* есть настройка привязки - **[изображение](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxgYn.png)**. К *localhost* при всём желании доступа извне вы получить не сможете, а наличие доменного имени и правильная настройка маршрутизации без проблем может организовать доступ извне. Про **launchSettings.json** не понимаю, откуда он у Вас в релизной версии, если он используется при дебаге проекта и запускается при старте приложения в **Visual Studio**

Comment: По локалке они должны проходить без доп конфигурации. Если хотите внешне подключать, то пробросте порты в фаерволе вашем.